# Make entire row in a table float while keeping all other rows in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a table cell to appear to be zoomable, that is, the table cell will appear to detach from its table and float freely.

The problem I'm facing now is that when there is no other cell in a row, the entire row collapses when its single cell floats.

See the code:

```
<body style="position: relative;">
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { text-align: center; }
        td {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: #0000ff;"></td>
            <td style="background: #00ff00;"></td>
            <td style="background: #ff0000;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="thistd" colspan="3" style="background: #808080; ">click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: #ffff00;"></td>
            <td style="background: #ff00ff;"></td>
            <td style="background: #00ffff;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#thistd')
            .css('cursor', 'pointer')
            .on('click', function() {
                $(this)
                    .css('position', 'absolute')
                    .css('left', '500px')
                    .css('top', '10px');
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Before clicking the table looks like:

[image: table before]

After clicking the table looks like:

[image: table after]

How to keep the middle row from collapsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script to insert a duplicate row when you float the row.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to move or collapse the row, then we could place a div in the row and make div to move as we want.like below

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="background: #808080; "><div id="thistd" style="background: 808080; click me</div></td>
</tr>
```

and javascript for this div is same as before

```
$('#thistd').css('cursor', 'pointer')
            .on('click', function() {
                $(this)
                    .css('position', 'absolute')
                    .css('left', '500px')
                    .css('top', '10px');
});
```

check this link http://jsfiddle.net/XhYs6/ still if it is not fulfilling the requirement ask for more...

Comment: I'll try this one. But I think I'll have problems with `<tr>` height, since in the target page its height is not defined by style, but by contents. As soon as I (dynamically) move the elements from `<td>` to the new `<div>` I'm sure the original `<td>` (and its `<tr>`) will collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `absolute`, try using `relative`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wVJB9/1/)

```
    $('#thistd')
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .on('click', function() {
            $(this)
                .css('position', 'relative')
                .css('left', '500px')
                .css('top', '10px');
        });
```

Please note that the `left` and `right` properties will be relative to its original position and not to the parent. However you may calculate for its position from the parent to somehow make it relative to it. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVJB9/5/)

```
$('#thistd')
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .on('click', function() {
            $(this)
                .css('position', 'relative')
                .css('left', 50)
                .css('top', -$(this).position().top + 10);
        });
```

Comment: +1 Very nice indeed, but I cannot accept the answer as you changed the document to use `<div>` instead of `<table>`  + `<tr>` + `<td>`. That would be ok if I was in control of the full page layout. But I'm programming a bookmarklet, so I have to work with is already there. Sorry if I let this info out, I thought it was not relevant. Now I see it is. Thanks anyway.